# Do Euler trails have to start and end at different vertices?

Tags: graphs

I am wondering whether every Euler graph is also traversable. I.e. are Euler circuits Euler paths, too? Therefore I am asking the question above.

I am explicitly asking "euler circuit ⇒ euler trail?".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are different. A walk is any sequence of vertices where every two consecutive vertices are connected via an edge. A trail is a walk where every edge is visited at most once. A circuit is a trail that starts and ends on the same vertex. A path is a trail where no vertex is visited twice and a cycle is a path that starts and ends on the same vertex.

So an Euler circuit is an Euler trail, but not necessarily vice versa.

Indeed, if your graph has two vertices with odd degree, it cannot have an Euler circuit, but it might have an Euler trail.

Comment: So Euler trails do not have to have different start and end nodes? To be maximal explicit.

Comment: That is correct.